# CUDA Rendering intermittently working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have a MSI GeForce GT 730 GPU, which has worked fantastically with Blender's GPU compute. However, lately I have been getting CUDA errors such as this one:
[image: CUDA Error]

This has happened several times before, all with different error messages, but usually I could just exit rendered view, and re-enter it, and the problem would be solved. Unfortunately, this is not the case. Also, this is not the `out of memory` error I have seen several people experience.

I'm using Windows 10 with 3GB of VRam, Blender Ver. 2.77a.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I restarted Blender, and it seems to be working. Although that may change   suddenly...

Comment: I've run into problems before if I set the tile size too large. This apparently even depended on the size of the scene. If a scene was VERY complex, I sometimes had to set the tile size smaller than usual. The error didn't look like this for me, but it's worth trying.

Comment: Thanks. I have been getting this on the default cube scene as well. If I get it again, I will definitely try that.

Comment: Oh, also add your Blender version to your question. That's prolly relevant ;-)